# Multiple UITableViewControllers

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

You can draw multiple instances of a class that sub classes UITableViewController but only the first seems to get any gestural recognition, it seems modal.

I assume the delegates and datasources are different as these are part of the instanced classes. I have considered creating my own viewController, delegate and datasource and using protocols.

From what I have read UITableViewController was designed around the iPhone so I wonder if a iPad non-modal version needs to be build.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I never tried something like this, but if you having problem only in receiving gestures try using 
[self.tableviewName becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: Not sure if it is just an issue with receiving gestures. I placed that  code in the actually subclass and it didn't work. In the iteration and instanced I placed try it and nothing either.

Comment: can't help much without seeing code.  see if you post some code